# PyQt windows - can't load any sql drivers at all

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using the PyQt binary for windows version 4.8.5 for Python 2.6. It seems like I can't load any sql drivers at all

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

```
QtSql.QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QPSQL')
QtSql.QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QMYSQL')
QtSql.QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QSQLITE')
```

Everything returns "False"

I checked in my directory, there are 4 dll's in there

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\sqldrivers

qsqlite4.dll
qsqlmysql4.dll
qsqlodbc4.dll
qsqlpsql4.dll
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, you need to compile the QPSQL dll yourself. I've not found a single reliable way to do this, sadly, which is extremely annoying.

Comment: Tyrant, thank you for your reply. I actually discovered that this is another error altogether, I'm editing my original post now :(

Comment: Have you initialiased the application? Add the line `app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])` as the first thing the program runs, else the dlls won't be initialised.

Comment: omg you're right. Thanks Tyrant I've been so confused about this for the past 6 hours o_O

Answer (score 1):

I use Python 2.7 under windows 10, Postgresql, and developt the gui in QT , use PyQt4 and QtSql. And use spyder. (In reality everything is included in Python ( x , y))

,-) but here is the easy solution. Open the file C:\Python27\qt.conf, First I had inside the file this lines:

```
Prefix = C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4
Binaries = C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4
```

then you add the next lines:

```
Plugins = C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins
Translations = C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/translations
```

Make sure that the plugins are in C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins. Then close python and open again. Then all work perfectly. You found the same answer here http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/01/24/pyqt-database-driver-loading-issues-on-windows-after-installing-pyside/